# guildMemberAdd event member variable returns client

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Yep member.user returns client/bot. Am I missing something. I checked the docs, it says 'The member that has joined a guild' for the member variable. I am really new to discord.js but this error doesn't make sense to me. I already toggled SERVER MEMBERS INTENT and PRESENCE INTENT.
Sorry for my bad english.

Code:

```
module.exports = (member) => {

    try {
        console.log(member.user.username)
        const guild = member.guild;
        console.log(guild)

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }

};
```

Output:

```
my bot's name
undefined
```

Comment: You're probably passing the client as the first argument in your command handler.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I feel dumb.

````
module.exports = (client,member) => {

    try {
        console.log(member.user.username)
        const guild = member.guild;
        console.log(guild)

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }

};```

Adding client arg fixes
````